# dropBox is not visible in the form - CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, dropzone.js, multifile-uploader

I am using the [CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload Plugin](https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload), and have following code inside `edit.ctp` but the drop box is not visible here.

```
<div class="useTypes form">

<?php echo $this->Form->create('UseType'); ?>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit Use Type'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Upload->edit('UseType', $this->Form->fields['UseType.id']);
    ?>
    </fieldset>

<?php 
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

but when I use the following code alone , it is visible

```
<?php echo $this->Upload->edit('UseType', $this->Form->fields['UseType.id']);?>
```

I tried this in cakephp 2.6 with default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to wrap `$this->Upload->edit()` inside a `<form>` tag, as it already creates its own form.

You might also need to replace:

```
$this->Form->fields['UseType.id']
```

with:

```
$this->Form->value('UseType.id')
```

In summary, this should work:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('UseType'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit Use Type'); ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('id');
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('description');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Upload->edit('UseType', $this->Form->value('UseType.id'));?>
```

**Edit**

If you need to upload files on your `/use_types/add` view, you can do the following.

In `UseTypeController::add()` include:

```
$this->set('id',CakeText::uuid()); //String::uuid() for CakePHP 2.6 or lower
```

and in `/app/View/UseTypes/add.ctp`:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $id)); ?>
```

The drawback is that if you fail to save your model after uploading files via AJAX, these will be left orphaned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I use this for adding a new record.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, as `UseType.id` must be known to the Component before it can upload a file. Remember we are dealing with AJAX, and the upload would take place before saving the `UseType` record. Note that you don't necessarily have to place the upload element in `edit.ctp`, it can go in `view.ctp`.

Comment: I found some websites like http://olx.in/posting/ and  http://delhi.quikr.com/post-classifieds-ads/?postadcategoryid=635  both using ajax for "add and edit" operations. So how do they do it.

Comment: Those are different implementations. A quick fix is to pre-generate an `UUID` in the add action and pass it on to the `add.ctp` view.